# Retrieve SQL Statement Does Not Go Into While Loop

Tags: sql, database, while-loop

I am having problem when doing retrieve function in 3-tier in C#. Here is the codes:

```
public DistributionStandardPackingUnits getSPUDetail(string distributionID)
{
    DistributionStandardPackingUnits SPUFound = new DistributionStandardPackingUnits();
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FoodBankDB.connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, description, quantity FROM dbo.DistributionStandardPackingUnits WHERE distribution = '" + distributionID + "'", connection);
        connection.Open();
        using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string name = dr["name"].ToString();
                string description = dr["description"].ToString();
                string quantity = dr["quantity"].ToString();

                SPUFound = new DistributionStandardPackingUnits(name, description, quantity);
            }
        }
    }
    return SPUFound;
}
```

When I run in browser, it just won't show up any retrieved data. When I run in debugging mode, I realized that when it hits the while loop, instead of executing the dr.Read(), it simply just skip the entire while loop and return null values. I wonder what problem has caused this. I tested my query using the test query, it returns me something that I wanted so I think the problem does not lies at the Sql statement.

Thanks in advance.

Edited Portion

```
public static SqlDataReader executeReader(string query)
    {
        SqlDataReader result = null;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FoodBankDB executeReader: " + query);

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        result = command.ExecuteReader();
        connection.Close();

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Well, then your query is not returning any rows back.

Comment: But when I test query there is something returned. What has caused the query is not returning any rows back?

Comment: Did you test the EXACT string that is in the code, or something you typed in a SQL IDE?  I would create a string variable and assign it the select, with your parameter ( which you need to change from a literal to a "real" parameter), print that out, and run it in your SQL IDE.  Are you sure you are connected to the correct database?

Comment: When I debugging, I saw the distributionID is 1. So I must type: SELECT name, description, quantity FROM dbo.DistributionStandardPackingUnits WHERE distribution = '1' inside the test query? And yup, my other retrieve functions work.

Comment: Also, don't you need to open the connection before creating the SqlCommand?  Not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Is distribution defined as a numeric or character type in the database?  Please show the table definition.  What database platform is this?

Comment: Its a string. I got another static method to set up the connection. See edited portion